# Temporary header for output buffer in PHP

Tags: php, binary-data, output-buffering

I convert binary data to JPEG. PHP is cool for this, because I need just to send `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg;');` and `echo` my binary.

But I have content above that binary like so:

```
echo 123;
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg;');
$data = hex2bin($CmnObiektZalacznik[0]->Binaria);
echo $data;
```

It will of course it will warn with `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by` so i thought it (header and binary JPEG) could be outputed to temporary buffer something like that:

```
echo 123;
ob_start();
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg;');
$data = hex2bin($CmnObiektZalacznik[0]->Binaria);
echo $data;
ob_end_flush();
```

But I get to do it?

Comment: What is the purpose of the 'temporary buffer'? One http request - one content-type, so how this buffer will help you? You can start buffering from the beginning and prevent `echo 123;`. You can save binary content to the temporary file and read it during another request.

Comment: I want to convert binary to JPEG and echo it as `<img>` HTML tag dynamicly

Comment: one request, one content-type. No mix between text and image. If image is small, you can use DATA URI inside of the html page. Otherwise, img tag should make a separate http request to get the image.

Comment: Is is up to you what to call a 'small image'. Estimate difference between increased size of the page and a separate request to the server. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme  ps: yes, IE8 has limit of 32KB of base64 encoded binary data.

Comment: Don't include semicolons `;` in your `Content-Type` header values for `image/jpeg`.

Comment: Use a AJAX request to get the image. Like Cheery said, you can't have multiple headers.

Comment: @Brad why dont use ;?

Comment: @Ultra Because `;` isn't part of the value here!